# How to change site URL on SharePoint 2019 server

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, domain

Currently, my SharePoint URL is like `http://servername/sites/xxx`, is it possible to change the URL to  another one? like `http://mycompanyname/sites/xxx`, so that users cannot see the actual server name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use AAM(alternate access mappings) to achieve it.
Steps for your reference:

1. Create a DNS host record using your company name and map it to your SharePoint server.
2. Binding the DNS host record in IIS.
3. Configure AAM in SharePoint Central Administration.

Detailed information, you can refer to:
https://howtodowithsharepoint.wordpress.com/2018/01/26/sharepoint-2016-how-to-implement-alternate-access-mapping/ (also work for SharePoint 2019)

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.